# Python, Numpy инициализация массива

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Привожу два примера в псевдокоде. Какие из условий (condition) будут выполнены, заранее неизвестно.

1. Создание массива, заполенного нулями.

   ```
   array = numpy.zeros(x)
   if condition1: 
        array = numpy.concatenate((array, newarray1))
   ...
   if conditionN:
        array = numpy.concatenate((array, newarrayN))
   array = array[1:, :] #отсекаю строку нулей, которой был инициализирован массив
   ```
2. Проверка на существование переменной в локальной области видимости в каждом условии.

   ```
   if condition1:
       if 'array' in locals():
           array = numpy.concatenate((array, newarray1))
       else:
           array = numpy.array(newarray1)
   ...
   if conditionN:
       if 'array' in locals():
           ...
   ```

Оба варианта кажутся костыльными. Как все-таки правильнее инициализировать массив с последующим его расширением?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие, то я бы записал так:

```
array = numpy.array([])
if condition1: 
    array = numpy.concatenate((array, newarray1))
...
if conditionN:
    array = numpy.concatenate((array, newarrayN))
```

Comment: Да, все так, спасибо. Не знал, что можно создавать массив из пустого листа.